# Microsoft Graph API - send message in channel by using team tagging

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

This graph API send a message in the channel

`POST` [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)

```
{
    "body": {
        "content": "Hello world"
    }
}
```

Also, following the docs from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagemention?view=graph-rest-1.0 I can mention **user, channel or team**

But I am looking for how I can mention **Tags** while sending message in a channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, came up with a solution thought of posting here for others:

**Graph API**

`POST` [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)

**Body here is critical**

```
{
    "subject": "This is very urgent!",
    "importance": "urgent",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Programatically mentioning of Tagged users  <at id=\"0\">String_1234</at>"
    },
    "mentions": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "mentionText": "String_1234",
            "mentioned": {
                "tag": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.teamworkTagIdentity",
                    "id": "",         //tag id
                    "displayName": "" //tag name
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, I tried before but was unable to do so, would be good if you or share with someone, thanks

Comment: I tried it and it's working fine.
We need to get the tag id and name via using Graph API for a channel and set it accordingly.

Comment: We can use this beta Graph API [List Team Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) with application or delegated permissions to list down tags created in that Team. Use Id and Display from its response to send message into channel (with the API you have mentioned)